# Unable to download Xcode update to 4.5.2 from iTunes store

Tags: xcode, itunes

I noted that there was an update to xcode available (to 4.5.2), but after not receiving any update notifications I logged into the iTunes store and tried to run 'update' from there.  It then replied that I needed to log into the iTunes store with the Apple ID that originally purchased the app.  I only have one Apple ID.  I recently upgraded the hard drive on my macbook.  I presume this error relates to the change in the hard-drive or to the change in the name of the drive I made during the upgrade.
Apple support suggest removing Xcode from my macbook and downloading and re-installing it from scratch.
Has anyone else experienced this issue and/or can offer some suggestions about the best way to go about the update in this situation?  Would re-using the /Applications/Install XCode.app on the machine be a way to get this to work?

Comment: ... Are you logged in to the app store? Have you tried removing XCode and re-installing?

Comment: No, I haven't tried removing Xcode as yet.  I am seeking advice prior to undertaking such a step.

Comment: How about you just move it somewhere else, and then try reinstalling? Then if something breaks you can just move it back.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am looking for a little more knowledgeable insight into exactly what the issue is with Xcode and the iTunes store.  I can live without the upgrade for awhile, but I can't afford to spend the time uninstalling, re-installing and then getting all my certificates, provisioning profiles and personalised settings back in place: no thanks.